# White screen on iOs Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a very basic application that has two buttons that are supposed to retrieve properties and display them on a label. The classes are simple, basically containing properties.

The thing that I am running into is that everytime I hit the play button, it showcases a screen that is all white/blank.

So far, I am assuming this is due to a goof up in the UI because as far as the classes are concerned, I am quite confident that they work i.e they do not report any errors.

This question is vague but if you guys have experienced a similar issue maybe you know what it is.

So I'll leave this question at this without inching into more description that is highly likely to be irrelevant.

Any leads people?

Comment: ,i think u didnt connect the view outlet in interface builde,when u tap the play button it goes to another page right?that shows the blank/white screen?

Comment: yes it goes to another page which is the iOS simulator (using xcode 4.1) where the screen just happens to be the blank white screen.

Answer (score 1):

When I was getting started with iOS stuff, I found a good way to debug weird `UIView` behaviour was to set the `backgroundColor` property of each view to a different colour, eg:

```
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

That way I could tell at least vaguely what was going on.